# How to add a prerequisite

Tags: morea-framework

Am trying to add another morea course as a prerequisite.
I have created a markdownfile prerequisite.md but do not know where to put it.
The online user guide states you can add a prerequisite but does not explain what to name the .md file or where to locate.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites are at the module level - a module references another module. In short: you create a prerequisite file and reference it in the referencing module header.

See the [bar folder](https://github.com/morea-framework/sample-morea-directory/tree/cabb68fa1169779d21f8632301f0f943de08ba87/morea/bar) of the example site, which references the other foo module:

module.md:

```
morea_prerequisites:
  - prerequisite-foo
```

prerequisite-foo.md:

```
morea_id: prerequisite-foo
morea_type: prerequisite
```

See also the [documentation example](http://morea-framework.github.io/userguide.html#Prerequisite).